# how to match python list using regular expression

Tags: python

I have following lists in python `["john","doe","1","90"]` and `["prince","2","95"]`. the first number column is field: id and second number field is score. I would like to use `re` in python to parse out the field and print. So far, I only know how to do split of field comma. Any one can help?

Comment: Did you try something? If yes please add it!

Comment: There are no commas to split on

Comment: `I would like to use re in python to parse out the field and print` - and what exactly forces you *not* to `import re` and use it?

Comment: Your examples are lists of strings, not themselves a single string. `re` is for finding patterns in a single string of characters — so it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a dictionary than a regex (which I don't see how you use here):

```
{'name': 'John Doe', 'id': '1', 'score': '90'}
```

Or better yet, use numbers:

```
{'name': 'John Doe', 'id': 1, 'score': 90}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regular expression here. You can just use isinstance() and slicing.

This should do what you want :

```
a_list = ['john','doe','1','90']

for i, elem in enumerate(a_list):
    try:
        elem = int(elem)
    except ValueError, e:
        pass
    if isinstance(elem, int):
        names_part = a_list[:i-1]
        id_and_score = a_list[i-1:]

        print 'name(s): {0}, '.format(' '.join(names_part)), 'id: {id}, score: {score}'.format(id=id_and_score[0], score=id_and_score[1])
```

Though, this solution could be improve if we were know the source of your data or if there is a way to pridict the field position you can just turn your list into a dict as suggested. If you extract your data you may consider building a dict instead of a list which prevent you from having to do what above.